# Get the colour of a pixel that has specific coordinates within a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, colors, awt

I am writing a program in which I need to find the colours of clicked pixels within an image (the image being stored as a JLabel), and plan to use an AWT Robot to do the job. However, as far as I know, I can't associate an AWT Robot with a specific label; it acts on the entire GraphicsDevice. The following command:

```
    Robot r = new Robot();
    Color c = r.getPixelColor(42, 42);
```

would get the colour of the pixel whose coordinates on the *screen* are (42, 42), rather than the colour of the one whose coordinates *within* the JLabel are (42, 42) (i.e., 42 pixels to the right and 42 pixels down from the top left corner of the JLabel). How could I obtain the colour of a pixel with specific coordinates within the JLabel?

I also have a MouseListener object in my JLabel if that could help.

Comment: *"(the image being stored as a JLabel), and plan to use an AWT Robot"*  Store the image as a `BufferedImage` and use [`BufferedImage.getRGB(x,y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB-int-int-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the screen coordinates of a Swing/AWT [Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen%28%29) using:

```
Component.getLocationOnScreen()
```

Then just use `getPixelColour` for those coordinates plus your offset of 42, 42 or whatever.